# if i write a code in android and run in my phone the text is overlapping.this is my code below

Tags: android

if i run this code in my phone all text view and button over lap to each and i use Constraint Layout

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="QUANTITY" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text= "ORDER"
    />
```

Comment: without the parent layout nobody will be able to help you

Comment: write full xml, it is depended on what layout do you use

Comment: use `LinearLayout` as parent layout and set orientation vertical this will solve your overlapping problem

Comment: Edit and show your complete XML code.

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious that you have these 2 textviews and a button inside the relative layout.

In RelativeLayout, the position of each view has to be specified as relative to sibling elements, if not given everything will be placed in the same position of the screen overlapping every view.

Your code should be like below :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="QUANTITY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/text1"
    android:text="0"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/text2"
    android:text= "ORDER"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```